# Как добавить атрибут с пользовательским типом данных при помощи @XmlAttribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Как сделать что бы X и Y были атрибутами тега .
Важно что бы эти атрибуты были полями класса  `Axes`, а в классе `Test` было поле `Axes`

```
<test xmlns="test" x="10" y="10">
</test>
```

Код который представлен ниже

```
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AxesAdapter.class)
    private Axes axes;

}

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Axes {
    private long x;
    private long y;
}

public class AxesAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AxesAdapter.AdaptedContactMethod, Axes> {

    @Override
    public Axes unmarshal(AdaptedContactMethod v) throws Exception {
        if (v != null) {
            return Axes.builder()
                    .x(v.x)
                    .y(v.y)
                    .build();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedContactMethod marshal(Axes v) throws Exception {
        if (v != null) {
            return AdaptedContactMethod.builder()
                    .x(v.getX())
                    .y(v.getY())
                    .build();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Builder
    public static class AdaptedContactMethod {

        @XmlAttribute
        private long x;
        @XmlAttribute
        private long y;

    }
}
```

выводит в следующем формате

```
<test>
    <axes x="10" y="10"/>
</test>
```